# Is my review confirmation counted to my review stats when someone else is faster?

Tags: support, review, review-stats

When the new review badges were introduced, I've started to actively review. I'm wondering, if my review confirmation will be counted to my stats when someone else will be faster.

---

***Situation:***

I open suggested edits, get some post to review and before I click approve or reject, someone else do it before me. Will my confirmation (my click on approve or reject) be counted to my stats ?

---

If no, then I'm afraid, that people will soon or later just click on any button without a real review of a post just to get point to the stats.

How does this counting work ? Will I get point to my stats even when I'm slower than the others ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So long as you don't receive an error on completing a review it will be counted and added to your stats.  There are situations where we have to stop and make you aware of important changes that did occur while you were viewing a review task.  We have plans for a few more real time features that will let you know the moment a review task is cleared instead of after you have already made a decision.